# Aws-sdk-php-laravel get 500 error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I follow aws-sdk-php-laravel readme.md to setup aws-sdk-php-laravel in laravel 5.2

In composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "3.1.0"
},
```

composer update

In config/app.php

providers add

```
Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class,
```

aliases add

```
'Aws' => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class,
```

php artisan vendor:publish

and one of controllers

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Aws;

$cloudSearchDomain = App::make('aws')->get('cloudsearchdomain', array('endpoint' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx));
```

always get

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\App' not found
```

If add

```
use App;
```

get

```
BadMethodCallException in Sdk.php line 178:
Unknown method: get.
```

but the same code work fine in laravel 4.2

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try replacing `App::make('aws')->get` with `Aws::get`

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Sdk.php line 178:Unknown method: get.

Comment: Ok, looking at the docs it looks like you have to do something like this before calling any methods such as `get`: `$xxx = AWS::createClient('name-of-aws-service-here');` So for Cloud Search Domain: `$csd = AWS::createClient('CloudSearchDomain')` then `$csd->get('blah');`

Comment: Try `\App::make...`.

Comment: Thanks @ntzm ,`$cloudSearchDomain = Aws::createClient('cloudsearchdomain',array('endpoint' => xxxxxxxxxxx));` It's worked.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen ,Still get `BadMethodCallException in Sdk.php line 178:
Unknown method: get.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cloudSearchDomain = App::make('aws')->createClient('cloudsearchdomain', [
    'endpoint' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
]);
```

or

```
$cloudSearchDomain = Aws::createClient('cloudsearchdomain', [
    'endpoint' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
]);
```